# redirect subdomain to https - nginx web server

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need to redirect client.mysite.com to https while client.mysite.com/admin should keep http. How can I achieve that on nginx web server ?

right now I use this for subdomain but redirects client.mysite.com/admin too :

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    my.domain.com;
   rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the redirection conditionally only on `location /`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    location = / {
        return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        # remaining rules
    }
}
```

Comment: If by 'thank you' you mean it solved your problem, could you be kind enough to mark my answer as correct ;-)